# Десериализация обьемных xml

Tags: c#, xml, serialize

Привет. Как можно десериализовать обьемный xml файл (около 7 или 8 Гигабайт) без кеширования ? Сейчас я делаю десериализацию, и программа забирает память пока не отвалится с исключением. Мне сказали, что можно воспользоваться классом XmlReader, но я не пойму как десериализовать напрямую в мой кастомный class.

Comment: А экземпляр класса не лопнет? :) 7-8 ГБ XML это где-то два-три ГБ памяти под экземпляр класса. Данные переносятся 1:1, имена тегов 1:2, скобки и whitespace 0:1, выходит где-то 1:3-1:4 для "prettified" XML (у которого отступы на вложенность выставлены на весь файл).

Comment: @Vesper: Но как-то же его надо распарсить и вытянуть нужные данные. Видимо вопрос в этом.

Comment: На каком примерно значении выеденной памяти и с каким исключенем падает? Приложение под x64/AnyCPU собрано?

Comment: Падает с эксепшном "XML файл поврежден <строка, позиция>". Номер строки всегда разный, в зависимости от того сколько было свободной памяти.. Файл валидный, сторонним софтом парсится.

Comment: @ВладимирК а какой сторонний софт вы используете?

Comment: Teoco Ultima Mentor

Comment: `XmlReader` правильный ответ, он не должен неограниченно использовать память с ростом входного файла. Дальше вопрос, что вы делаете с его результатами. Уточните, что конкретно вам нужно получить на выходе и конкретно что неясно с XmlReader.